# Python - Filter dataframe by several criteria

Tags: python, dataframe, filter

I have a dataframe that has four columns: ID, year, number, source. IDs might IDs and years can be duplicated for source1 and source2. Within source2, several rows might have the same ID and year. For example:

```
data = {
    'ID': [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3],
    'year': [2021, 2021, 2021, 2021, 2022, 2022, 2022, 2021],
    'number': [400, 300, 450, 200, 500, 600, 100, 700],
    'source': ['source1', 'source1', 'source2', 'source2', 'source2', 'source2', 'source2', 'source2']
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I would like to filter the dataframe, so that:

1. If for a given ID an year source 1 is available it uses that and drops the row for that ID and year with source 2. Put differently, only uses source 2 for a given ID and year if source 1 is not available for that ID and year

2. If it uses source2 and there are several IDs and years available it keeps all of them.

In the desired output dataframe row 2 and 3 are dropped as for the same ID and year source1 is available. But row 4 is kept as while it is the same ID as in row 0 the year is different. Row 5 and 6 are also kept, as while the same ID is available for source1, the year is different. Row 7 is kept because the same ID and year is not available for source1

I tried the following. It seems to work for the example dataframe. But when I apply it to my actual (much larger) dataset it doesn't work. I can't figure out why.

```
source1Mask = df\["source"\] == "source1"

source2Mask = (df\["source"\] == "source2") & \~((df\["ID"\].isin(df\[source1Mask\]\["ID"\])) & (df\["year"\].isin(df\[source1Mask\]\["year"\])))

finalMask = source1Mask | source2Mask 
filtered_df = df[finalMask]
```

The following also seems to work, but doesn't seem like the most efficient solution.

```
grouped = df.groupby(\['ID', 'year'\])

df\['source1count'\] = grouped\['source'\].transform(lambda x: (x == 'source1').sum()).fillna(0)

df\['source2count'\] = grouped\['source'\].transform(lambda x: (x == 'source2').sum()).fillna(0)

filtered_df = df\[(df\["source"\] == "source1") | ((df\["source1count"\] == 0) & (df\["source2count"\] \>= 1))\]
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work" ? Is the output wrong or do you get an error message ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. The output is wrong. It filters out some rows that should actually be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used `lambda` function checks if 'source1' is available in the `source` column for that group. If it is, it selects only the rows with 'source1', otherwise, it keeps all the rows for that group.

```
filtered_df = df.groupby(['ID', 'year']).apply(lambda x: x[x['source'] == 'source1'] if 'source1' in x['source'].values else x)
filtered_df = filtered_df.reset_index(drop=True)
filtered_df
```

Output-

```
   ID  year  number   source
0   1  2021     400  source1
1   1  2022     500  source2
2   2  2021     300  source1
3   2  2022     600  source2
4   2  2022     100  source2
5   3  2021     700  source2
```

`filtered_df` filters where `source1` is used if available, and `source2` is used only if `source1` is not available for a given `ID` and `year`.

- Row 2 and Row 3 are dropped as for same id and year, source1 is available.

`df`-

```
   ID  year  number   source
0   1  2021     400  source1
1   2  2021     300  source1
2   1  2021     450  source2
3   1  2021     200  source2
4   1  2022     500  source2
5   2  2022     600  source2
6   2  2022     100  source2
7   3  2021     700  source2
```

Comment: Do you know why my original version doesn't work (the one with (source1Mask, source2Mask)?

Comment: No I haven't tried, but seems it should work, I just took your word that you said output it shows is incorrect for larger dataset.  but  will try..